# How to get or pick local GIF file from device

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-image, flutter-video-player

I have done lots of R&D about the pick-only GIF file and all give results only display or showing GIF files but
I want to only pick GIF files from a local device like images or videos.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package and set the `allowedExtensions` to `gif`.

```
allowedExtensions: ['gif']
```

here is an example:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _selectedFile;
  String customAppLogoName;
  _openFileManager() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['gif'],
    );
    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile selectedFile = result.files.first;
      setState(() {
        _selectedFile = File(selectedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("File Picker"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _openFileManager();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: _selectedFile == null
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.broken_image,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                    Text('no image'),
                  ],
                )
              : Image(
                  image: FileImage(_selectedFile),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It's working but also the image file selectable.